# Ocaml syntax error: why are parentheses enclosing (if ...) in function application necessary?

Tags: parsing, ocaml

Entering this code to ocaml toplevel results in syntax error.

```
(fun n -> n + 1) if true then 1 else 2
```

But this code is OK.

```
(fun n -> n + 1) (if true then 1 else 2)
```

Why are parentheses necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the priority table of [ocaml operators priority](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#). A function has left associativity, whereas if does not have associativity.

Answer (score 2):

Because an expression like

```
f if a then b else x y
```

would be ambiguous (besides being hard to read).